# Solve this systems to condition $3x^3(x+1)^2=2y^2(z+3)^3$

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

if $x,y,z$be postive real numbers, solve  systems of this following equation
$$
3x^3(x+1)^2=2y^2(z+3)^3\tag{1}$$
$$3y^3(y+2)^2=2z^2(x+1)^3\tag{2}$$
$$3z^3(z+3)^2=2x^2(y+2)^3\tag{3}$$

My approach is as follows: $(1)\times(2)\times (3)$,we have
$$27xyz=8(x+1)(y+2)(z+3)$$but I have no idea how to continue. Can someone help me?Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "solve this system to $$(x+1):(y+2):(z+3)$$"?

Comment: Do you require $x,y,z$ to be real? Integers? There seems to be one real solution and no integer solutions.

Comment: $x,y,z$ postive real numbers.

Comment: If you drop the positive requirement then the other solution with $xyz\ne0$ is $(-1,-2,-3)$

Comment: @almagest I see the mistake: $(x,y,z)=(-1,-2,-3)$ is not satisfying $27xyz=8(x+1)(y+2)(z+3)$, which I have assumed.

Comment: I seem to get $x = \frac{86}{19}, y = \frac{70}{19}, z = \frac{72}{19}$ as the only positive solution...

Comment: @Macavity Yes. I agree. The earlier solution I got was due to a typo in my equations. That suggests where must be an easier way to get it!

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Buchberger algorithm for it over the complex numbers, and assuming the additional equation
$$27xyz=8(x+1)(y+2)(z+3),$$
I obtain the following real solutions: Either one of $x,y,z$ is zero, or 
$$
(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{86}{19},\frac{70}{19},\frac{72}{19}\right).
$$
It would be interesting to know the context in which these equations arise, and to ask for all rational solutions of this system of polynomial equations.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how you get the solutions? I have never used the Buchberger algorithm in anger on a non-trivial case ...

Comment: This works with the "multivariate division" in the polynomial ring $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ of $n$ variables (here $n=3$), which replaces the Euclidean algorithm in $K[x]$. It is not easy to write down all details (but see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm)); I obtain some nice short polynomials, but also a huge one, which I have to eliminate.

Comment: You used the $27xyz\dots$ equation? [Its derivation assumes $x,y,z\ne0$ and also $x\ne-1,y\ne-2,z\ne-3$.] Did you make any additional assumptions to eliminate the huge polynomial you got?

Comment: No, only the assumption positive real numbers.